# Google Calendar API vendor/autoload.php: failed to open stream

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm working with Google Calendar and their [PHP tutorial](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php). I followed all the instructions to the letter however at the part where it says to run it from the console/command line I get this obvious error:

> Warning: require(D:\htdocs\test/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in D:\htdocs\test\quickstart.php on
>   line 4

There is no `vendor/autoload.php` file in the tutorial nor on the [Github repository](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/php-samples/tree/master/calendar/quickstart).

Where do I find the `autoload.php` file and why do they insist on requiring it but not providing it?

Comment: Have you enable composer ?

Comment: @Flyzzx "I followed all the instructions to the letter"

Comment: I have done the `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0` and I have the autoload.php in the vendor directory

Comment: @Flyzzx *Where* does composer install the files to? My development machine is Windows.

Comment: In the directory where you run the command

Comment: Okay - I see it there. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176960/discussion-between-flyzzx-and-john).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run composer in the directory of your project. For eq :

```
cd D:\htdocs\test\
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```